# Bind a JsonResult to a drop down list in asp net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having problems with filling a drop down list in asp.net mvc 5. So I have this in my view

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Getdata", "Data", FormMethod.Get))
{
<p>
    Choose your type of data: @Html.DropDownList("SearchString") <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>

}
```

And this is the controller method

```
     public JsonResult Getdata(string search)
    {
        var data = (from m in db.ABC
                          select search).Distinct();

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

And this is the model

```
 public class ABC
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }


    public class  ABCDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ABC> ABC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So what do I need to change in order to fill the drop down list with the data types ABC has?

Comment: Are you using Ajax to get the Dropdown values?

Comment: @Dawood Awan no, not really why?

Comment: So then post you data in the view model in the form as Dictionary<int, string>, I don't see the point in using JSON when you are not posting back to get the data, you are creating the Dropdown on page load

Comment: Nothing here makes sense. Where are you calling `public JsonResult Getdata(string search)`? What is `@Html.DropDownList("SearchString")` binding to? Where to you create the `SelectList`? You need to post the  controller GET method that generates your view